# Back button scrolls to wrong position

Tags: bug, android-app

Open [this post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606056/176217) in the Android app.

Tap on the link:

> [image: link]

Wait for loading and tap on back button:

> [image: back]

Post showed in wrong position:

> [image: shift]

Link is out of screen.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (1634100298931)

Comment: And if you click the app back button? (in the top left)

Comment: @ShadowWizard same as for system back button.